# install4j JRE bundled Linux not supported?

Tags: install4j

from within the IDE I do not see linux bundle. The IDE allows choosing the Mac bundle, however after downloading that the installation does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still possible to create your own JRE bundles on Linux with Project->Create a JRE bundle and the bin/createbundle command line utility.

We have discontinued the official JREs bundles for Linux and Unix. They have created lots of problems for our customers (and consequently for us) since JRE binaries only work for a certain range of distributions. It is not within our abilities to map this parameter space. Also, 64-bit distributions with incomplete 32-bit libraries lead to failures of JRE bundles.

When there is a problem with a JRE bundle, we cannot provide any satisfactory solution. The only safe way is to install the JRE that comes with the distribution. Since Java is open source, it should be easy to install it through the distribution.

Of course it would be desirable if JRE bundles simply worked on Linux, but they don't. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: How about using Zulu from Azul (See https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/)? These are direct OpenJDK builds for Win/Lin/Mac, not burdened by package manager decisions on Linux. (~80 MB for Java 8) They say it's fully FOSS, and guarantee that their builds don't force GPLing anything that includes them. (Disclaimer: I haven't used Zulu myself.)

Comment: It's not a legal problem, it's a problem against which other libraries the JRE is linked.

Comment: If Zulu has a "Linux" download without mention of distros/versions, it should run everywhere; maybe it's statically linked? But I admit I haven't checked. --- Azul's repackaging work might be interesting for EJ Tech even if it's just for Win/Mac: they likely had to solve the same issues but could throw more manpower at them. --- (I mentioned legal aspects just to get the "can EJ redistribute that" issue out of the way.)

Comment: All OpenJDK are linked somehow and dependencies like X server libraries cannot be static. The question is if the distro has the actual dependencies. This is a common problem for binary artifacts on Linux. An OpenJDK version that has been compiled for a specific distro is guaranteed to work there.

Comment: Right, they have "reference platforms" that they priorize bug fixing on. I guess they're solving this with manpower, the list on https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zulurelnotes/Content/ZuluReleaseNotes/SupportedPlatforms.htm isn't exhaustive but pretty impressive anyway.

Comment: Hmm... what about making install4j support Zulu as an additional JRE source? It would certainly expand install4j's scope.

Comment: You can create JRE bundles from Zulu OpenJDK with Project->Create a JRE Bundle or the bin/createbundle command line tool. There's also AdoptOpenJDK and soon Amazon Corretto. We just don't want to publish these bundles in our bundle download because then customers blame us if they do not work on some distro.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a viable plan. We're going to use this in a project this year (around summer I guess), so if you don't hear until then it worked for us :-)